# Webform component permission

Tags: webforms, tokens, users

I have webform in my site, so I need to do that there are 2 user approval field components in my webform so they both should be unique value, in my case its working like if my name is joy then I submit that form then it will display joy on both field's value.

I want to just display only one field joy and another field value get from another user. please let me know if anyone has solution for this.

Comment: The questions doesn't seems to be clear enough. Please update with some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using [Field Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Or first you have to create a user role. And apply condition to fields as per role.

Or you can use [User Role Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_role_field) module.